# Cloud Build keeps failing after GCS settings changed

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I'am using app engine for my Nodejs angular project. After i recently discovered Cloud Build i started to use it.It is really good.

But i noticed im getting billed for some reason and it was Google Storage. I dont directly use Google Storage but i think some build files getting uploaded to Google Storage

When i checked the Google Storage buckets, i saw buckets which, I think, is used by app engine internal.

I wanted to clear those buckets because i was getting billed. I set those buckets to be deleted after 1 day. Then errors started to occur

Cloud build keeps failing with following logs;

```
Step #1 - "builder": <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: eu.artifacts.{PROJECTID}/containers/images/sha256:c2c084020b88d7284aa14e388a04e651fc0be2813d89491031bd23e8f6b13514</Details></Error>: None
```

If i completely delete those gcs buckets, the first build success and those buckets created automatically. Then it keeps failing again.

My CI/CD is now interrupted by this problem. How can i solve this permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please contact App Engine support at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry to report this issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you do an App Engine flex deployment, a docker image with your code and base runtime is build. This is stored in Cloud Storage and you can check it in the Cloud Build dashboard. If you delete the bucket then it’s normal for the Cloud Build to fail. It’s also normal to be recreated as it’s necessary for the system to work. This is intended behavior.

Comment: Yes but after it is re-created, the build keeps failing time to time for same reason without me changing any gcs bucket option.

Comment: There's no way to set the default class of that bucket to regional to avoid costs.